# Is it legal to add class/id to HTML5 semantic Elements like <header class="header-1">?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I would like to add a class to  elements, it works but would like to know if it's legal.

Comment: Please, refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3919471/4443053  Basically, yes you can do that (it is legal).

Comment: Can you explain why you thought it might not be legal? Is there some website that hints it's not or something?

Comment: @MrLister: I though they were used exclusively declare different parts of a document and using ids and classes was not valid code and would show error in w3c validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is fine to add classes or id's to any valid markup such as `<header>`, but i would do it only if it adds further value to the selectivity, since you can always target it as

```
//css
header {//CSS style rules}
```

but if you want to add it it will be valid and correct

```
   //css
 .someClass{//CSS style rules}

//html
<header class='someClass'>Title</header >
```

Comment: I was concerned about the newly added elements.

Comment: Newly added elements like <header> <section> <article> etc

Comment: yes - sorry - just got that from re-reading your question title. Answer amended to reflect that :))

Comment: It is not only acceptable but it is also encouraged if you are going to be assigning styles to that element.  The trend now is to use class selectors instead of element selectors in your css.  This is because class selectors resolve quicker then do element selectors.  Plus it keeps you from relying on descendent selectors which can cause specificity issues. And, yes, every single HTML element accepts class and id attributes.

Comment: For reference you can check what's acceptable on any HTML element in the W3 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html#header

"Permitted Attributes" are all global attributes: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html