# Why is the box not 100% height?

Tags: html, css

Why is the div with the class `box` not 100% height?

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
*, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.box {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
}

  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="box">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}


  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="box">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Why is the body not 100%? I set `min-height: 100%;`!

Comment: html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }

Comment: Why not `min-height`?

Comment: I updated my post. The second paragraph has a white background why?

Comment: HTML, * { height: 100vh}

Comment: Also your `p` are also set to 100% height because of the `*` selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

You need to add 100% height to body and html. Your mistake was to add 100% to * which applies to every element (including your paragraphs)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>


  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="box">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I always have problems with `height: 100%`.

Try to set your body to the 100 of the screen:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

because your body is not 100% : use follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    *, html {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    .box {
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: brown;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body class="box"> //will make body same as div

    <div class="box">
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not 100%? I set it with `min-height: 100%;`.

Comment: body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
you did not gave . or # before body. you can do as well.. it will be more precise

Comment: please refer this too <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919456/class-or-id-on-body-tag?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa>